# why require is not working in webpack-simple vue-cli project

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

```
Vue.component('another-component', require('./components/AnotherComponent.vue'));
```

This way of declaring components is working properly in laravel-vue project but its is not working in webpack-simple vue project with vue-cli. Is there any reason why is it not working or whats wrong with it.

In webpack-simple vue-cli project I needed to import files in each and every component but in the laravel project once I declare I am able to use is anywhere. why is it happening? And how can I use the same laravel way of declaring components in webpack-simple vue-cli project.